# converting implicit routing to explicit routing in laravel for better understanding?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have the below route:

```
Route::controller('admin/categories' , 'CategoriesController');
```

How do i convert it to an explicit route in Laravel ?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your controller methods.

But a base code is

```
Route::get('admin/categories', ['uses' =>'CategoriesController@getIndex']);

Route::post('admin/categories', ['uses' =>'CategoriesController@postIndex']);

Route::post('admin/categories/create', ['uses' =>'CategoriesController@postCreate']);
```